# Meaning of a Dirac function

Tags: calculus, dirac-delta

My question is about the $\delta$ function. It has following property:
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\delta (x-t) \,\mathrm{d} x = f(t) $$
What's the meaning of the equation?
Why not directly calculate $f(t)$?

Comment: It turns out this formalism has a lot of applications, particularly in solving differential equations.

Comment: This is something called the [sifting property](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SiftingProperty.html), and *is* used to calculate $f(t)$.

Comment: If you've studied vector calculus, you might be interested to note that it pops up naturally here: $$\nabla\cdot\left(\frac{\hat{r}}{\|r\|^{2}}\right)=4\pi \delta^{3}(\vec{r})$$ And this is extremely useful in deriving Coulomb's law for a pointlike particle.

Comment: The Dirac's delta $\delta$ is defined in terms of area.  The equation you wrote is the sampling property of $\delta$, very useful in signal processing. You can learn more about this function in http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DeltaFunction.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Dirac-delta function, $\delta(x)$, is strictly speaking not a function. It is a distribution and the equation you have above is actually a defining property of the Dirac-delta function - it only makes mathematical sense under an integral.

What the equation intuitively

$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) \delta(x - t) dx = f(t)$

means is that $\delta(x)$ vanishes identically everywhere expect at the origin, where it is infinitely peaked.

The equation isn't used to find $f(x)$; rather, it tells you how a $\delta$-function affects $f(x)$ when integrated against it.

$\delta$-functions are extremely useful and show up everywhere in physics and mathematics, for instance, when solving certain differential equations.

Comment: I think it might be better to say that the equation *intuitively* means that. Rigorously it means exactly what it says, nothing more, nothing less. We can use approximate identities to make that intuition precise, but at the end of the day the definition is what it is. I stress this because in my experience the "infinite peak" idea doesn't actually help you calculate anything.

Comment: That's right, I should make that explicit.

Comment: It is not true that «it only makes mathematical sense under an integral». The integral appearing in the question is not an integral in any sensible sense.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez That's a bit pedantic. The basic examples of distributions are integration against reasonable functions. We think of distributions which are not functions as "integration" against some "function" which is not strictly speaking a function. This formalism is actually rather productive; it informs us of how to define the convolution of two distributions, and how to define the Fourier transform of a tempered distribution.

Comment: No, it is not pedantic a all. The evaluation of a disribution at a test function is most certainly not an integration. Things are set up so that it *behaves* like an integration, of course, but that does not make it an integration. Integration against functions does define distributions, but that has nothing to do with this. The integral sign appearing in the OP's question is a convenient notation, not an integral.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez It's not strictly speaking an integration, so perhaps there should be a variant on the word "intuition" in that sentence, but that is a key part of the idea. And as I said, without that idea, I don't see how we would have come up with the definition of the convolution of two distributions, or the Fourier transform of a tempered distribution. These are both very important concepts.

Comment: It is not an integration even when not speaking strictly. 97% of the problems the "delta function" causes arise because people confuse it with a function and because people think it is "integrated". That the notion of distributions is motivated by integration is true, but the whole point is that they are *not* integration against functions: it they were, they would be (mostly) useless.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez I agree it causes a lot of problems, but that doesn't mean we shouldn't teach the intuitive content. We should teach both, so that people learn what they *can* prove, *how* to prove those things, and what they *cannot* prove. For another example, how would you come up with the formula $\delta(f(x)) = \sum_{y : f(y)=0} \frac{\delta(x-y)}{|f'(y)|}$, where $f$ is $C^1$ with no non-simple roots? I can easily give a heuristic justification of this by writing an integral and then "pretending" that change of variables makes sense.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez Similarly we come up with the derivative of a distribution by "pretending" that integration by parts makes sense.

Comment: Andá you can pretende that you can multiply distributions, too. And you can't. Teaching the intuitive content of things does *not* mean telling them that the integral in the OP's question is an integral.

Comment: You can motivate the definition of differentiation using the fact that integration by parts works for functions, and being explicit about tthe fact that you extrapolate that to distributions: that is different from pretending it works for distributions. The difference is conceptual, and psychological— but there is a difference. In my experience, this "pretending" that you suggest is only helpful for people who have already understood the stuff.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez I guess our experiences have been rather different. Everyone around me who has studied this has learned by starting with the definition of a distribution, writing down the kinds of things that we intuitively want to happen, and then writing down the only definition that makes that possible.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez For derivatives, we want integration by parts to make sense; for the Fourier transform, we want it to be unitary with respect to the dual pairing; for composition of distributions with functions, we want integration by substitution to work; for convolutions of distributions with functions, we want the integral form of convolution to work; for convolution of two distributions, we want associativity of convolution to work.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez The only things I've seen that we might intuitively want that don't work are multiplication of distributions and convolution of two non-compactly-supported distributions. So that's five nontrivial things that work the way you naively expect, and two that don't. Can you think of any other things that don't work the way you naively expect?

Comment: Thanks for the answers. After taking a look at the notation of _distribution_ I have a better understanding of that now.

Answer (score 3):

Aegon's answer gives an idea of the meaning. I'd like to say a little bit about why you would want such a thing. The basic application is to solutions of differential equations, and the idea is the following abstract calculation. Suppose you want to be able to solve the differential equation

$$Lu=f$$

where $L$ is some differential operator, $u$ is the unknown function, and $f$ is a given function. We'll say it's on the full space to avoid boundary issues, although this is useful in boundary value problems as well.

When studying this, it would be nice if we had a single, unified approach, so that we could solve the equation for one $f$ and then get a representation of the solution for every other $f$. The way that we do this is based on your equation, which can be abstractly written as

$$\delta * f = f$$

where $*$ denotes convolution. This means that if we can find $g$ such that

$$Lg=\delta$$

then we can convolve with $f$ on both sides to get

$$Lg*f=f.$$

Finally if we can argue that $Lg*f=L(g*f)$, then we've solved the problem, and $g*f$ is our solution. This $g$ is called the Green's function or the fundamental solution for $L$. Like the Dirac delta, $g$ is never strictly speaking a function, it is always a distribution, although it is often a function away from $0$. It can be found explicitly in a number of very important examples, including linear ODEs with constant coefficients, and the three "classic" PDE, i.e. the Laplace, heat, and wave equations.

Comment: @Aegon@MarianoSuárez-Alvarez  Good explain. My question is from MDP(Markov Decision Process). They use that equation to calculate the transition function $f(x_{k+1}|x_k,a_k)$ with noise $w_k$, whose density is $f_k ^w(w_k)$. The model is like this $x_{k+1}=h(x_k, a_k, w_k)$. Then they use the following equation:$$f(x_{k+1}|x_k,a_k)= \int \delta (x_{k+1}-h(x_k, a_k, w_k))\cdot f_k ^w(w_k)\, \mathrm{d}w_k$$ So I can't figure out why they do that. If we know $f_k ^w(w_k)$ already. Why don't we calculate $f(x_{k+1}|x_k, a_k)=f_k ^w(x_{k+1}- h(x_k, a_k))$ instead.

Comment: @Micheal That formula should be understood as "integrate $f_k^w(w_k)$ only over the set given by $x_{k+1}=h(x_k,a_k,w_k)$". So you don't integrate over all values of $w_k$. You can think of it as just like restricting the limits of integration, except that it generalizes in the right way to surfaces. (For example, integrating against $\delta(x^2+y^2-1)$ over $\mathbb{R}^2$ amounts to integrating over the circle.) In practice you use the co-area formula to perform these calculations if you're doing them by hand.

Comment: I can get the idea of what you talked about. But the point is why not directly calculate it and why we have to use the $\delta$ function.

Comment: @Micheal I would think of it as an intermediate step in the calculation. Like if $(X,Y)$ have joint pdf $f$, and you want $E(X|h(Y)=z)$, then this is $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_{-\infty}^\infty x f(x,y) \delta(h(y)-z)$. Then if I needed to actually calculate this I would use the co-area formula.